# Unable to convert IEnumerable<int> to List<T> in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a query like this

```
IEnumerable<int> companies = Employers
                             .Where(p => p.Id == User.ID
                             .SelectMany(p => p.companies)
                             .Select(p => p.Id);


return Employers
       .Where(p => companies.Contains(p.Companies)
       .Include(p => p.FirstName)
       .ToList();
```

Here `p.Companies` refers to

```
Public Virtual List<Company>
```

under the class `Employers`.

This error occurs:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains>(IQueryable>,List)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable>'

Comment: Search the web.  This question has been asked lots of times.  The error message is very clear.  You need to add IQuertable to a class object.

Comment: I am new to Entity Framework. I couldn't find a solution. Please someone help me find a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982108/making-a-custom-class-iqueryable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this:

```
Where(p => companies.Contains(p.Companies)
```

you try to check if `companies` (`IEnumerable<int>` from previous query) contains some companies (object), not `int` value.

You can't check if collection of `int` values contains some value which is not `int`(`Company` is some object).

If you want to query all employers which have company with `Id` that is in `companies` variable use this `Linq` query:

```
return Employers
       .Where(p => p.Companies.Any(c => companies.Contains(c.Id)))
       .Include(p => p.FirstName)
       .ToList();
```